# Set out of office message for others using Microsoft APIs

Tags: c#, .net-core

Currently I am setting out of office message for others using PowerShell with basic authentication.

For security reasons need to implement without basic auth.

Is it possible to implement OOO using Graph api or any other Microsoft APIs?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible using the graph API. You need your users or an admin to consent to `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite` persmissions.

After that you can modify the `mailboxSettings`, for example https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('username')/mailboxSettings",
    
    "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time",
    "delegateMeetingMessageDeliveryOptions": "sendToDelegateOnly",
    "dateFormat": "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "timeFormat": "HH:mm",
    "userPurpose": "user",
    "automaticRepliesSetting": {
        "status": "disabled",
        "externalAudience": "none",
        "internalReplyMessage": "",
        "externalReplyMessage": "",
        "scheduledStartDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2022-08-27T08:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "scheduledEndDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2022-08-28T08:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    },
```

And the documentation for the object in question is at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/resources/automaticrepliessetting?view=graph-rest-1.0

You would retrieve them somewhere along those lines:

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var me = await graphClient.Me
    .Request()
    .Select("MailboxSettings")
    .GetAsync();

var mailboxSettings = me.MailboxSettings;
```